# Convert image to string without saving image

Tags: php, image-processing

I know that there is quite a lots this question on stack overflow but I don't think my question is the same.

I want to convert an Image resource to a string without having to save the image to the disk.

Is there a function for that, that im am not aware of and that i did not got able to find in the pass hour of searching Google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any of the `image*` functions that output an image as a stream and use output buffering to capture it:

```
ob_start();
// example for jpeg
imagejpeg($resource);
$image_string = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Will this output the content of imagejpeg() and store it in the variable or only store it in the var ?

Comment: Thanks It working !  Exsactly as I wanted it.  I didn't know you could actually use the buffer to actully get some stuff. This could be very usefull to gather some outputed html..  Any how thanks i will mark your awnser as apcepted as soon as stack over flow let me.  Since it is still to soon.  Thanks again!